# Couldn't find package "chalk@^1.1.3" required by "babel-code-frame@^6.26.0" on the "npm" registry (yarn add)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I've looked online for similar problems and haven't really found anything.
Below is the error in more detail. This error is followed by a slew of similar errors complaining about missing dependencies. Any help is appreciated, thanks :).

```
Error: Couldn't find package "chalk@^2.1.0" required by "eslint" on 
the "npm" registry.
at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:237:66)
at new MessageError (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:266:123)
at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:36410:17)
at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
at step (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:98:30)
at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:111:13
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Are you downloading from the official npm repository, or do you have to download from a company internal nexus? If so, the packages needs to be added to the nexus, first.

Comment: NPM registry can be configured globally or on a per-project basis. Run `npm config get registry` in the directory where the `package.json` lyies to find which registry your project uses.